# React: infinite loop even though useEffect should detect change and prevent loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

```
const [label, setLabel] = useState([<>, <>]);
const [labelType, setLabelType] = useState('none');

 useEffect( () => {
   if (props.label === 'label1') { 
      setLabel([<div>...</div>, <div>...</div>])
   }
   if (props.label=== 'label2') {
      setLabel([<div>...</div>, <div>...</div>]);
   }
   if (props.label === 'label3') {
      setLabel([<div>...</div>, <div>...</div>])
   }
}, [labelType] );

setLabelType(props.label)

return (
    <div className=''>
        <div id=''>{label}</div>
    </div>
)
```

So I'm basically passing in a prop and just trying to use that value to decide what to set my {label} to and the initial value of props.label is 'label1'. If my console logs, I see that 'none' is changed to 'label1' by setLabelType(props.label) and my understanding is that since setLabelType() was used, the stated is updated/ component re-rendered and plus labelType specifically is changed then useEffect() is triggered and the appropriate branch/setLabel() is called based on props. Next render useEffect() is not called since 'label1' -> 'label1' is no change (vs. first time 'none' -> 'label1').

But reality is that I have an infinite loop instead, could anyone explain to me why? **I think maybe I need to have setLabelType(props.label) in a function but the trigger for this code to execute is in a different component so there's no 'onChange' prop that would call it in this component (basically when sibling component is clicked, passes data to common parent, parent passes data back down to this child and use the prop to decide render).**  This seems really simple but I'm confused.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, put setters into a function so they're triggered conditionally somehow. Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop. As an aside, prefer posting a [mcve] than a snippet of the component that isn't complete (header and props aren't shown).

Comment: So its always the case that useState's setters have to be inside some function correct? Or does it have to be inside some function OR conditional statement; otherwise it justs keep updating right?

But the thing is that my situation isn't really conditional; once the other component gets clicked I always want my code in this component to run.

Comment: Maybe just switch on `props.label`, no need for an effect or state as far as I can tell. State is only needed when something might change or update within the component from one render to the next.

Comment: Well I don't want to use props.label directly I want to set certain (array of ) html elements at {label} based on props.label; {label} is not a single value using props.label; but actually I think I have an idea with useEffect( () => {...}, [ ] ); are you familar with when a component is 'dismounted'?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for the help, I figured it out by tracking the changes in the prop instead of the state